# Fetch single object from nested data in redux - Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have this data in my redux store:

```
data: [
    0: {
        name: "Mark Zuckerburg",
        description: "Facebook CEO"
    },
    1: {
        name: "Sheryl Sandberg",
        description: "Facebook COO"
    },
    2: {

    }
]
```

Here's is my code in reducer:

```
// This is how I store my data lists
case GET_HEROES_SUCCESS: {
            return Object.assign({}, state.data, {
                data: action.data
            });
        }
// This is how I fetch currently the single object in the data lists.
case FETCH_HEROES_REDUX_STORE: {
            return { ...state, data: state.data[action.id] }
        }
```

My problem now is if I dispatch the `FETCH_HEROES_REDUX_STORE` it overrides the whole data lists in my store. How can I return only the single data object base on the `action.id` by not overriding the whole data store.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Redux, actions are used to update and modify state. They are not typically used to fetch data. This is because any object returned by a reducer will take the place as the new Redux state, which is why the FETCH_HEROES_REDUX_STORE overrides your data list.

To get a single object from nested data in Redux, you want to pass the Redux store to your React component with the Provider react-redux component. I encourage you to look at the Redux docs to better understand data flow in Redux: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html.

In your most top-level component, do the following to connect your React components to the Redux store. This makes the Redux store available to all Container components in your React app.

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import todoApp from './reducers'
import App from './components/App'

let store = createStore(todoApp)

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

And then, to pass the Redux state tree to a React component, you connect a Container component to Redux. Note: you want to render this container component somewhere in your React app.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import ReactComponent from './react_component' // import a React component

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    heroes: state.data // this will return the heroes data directly into your React components so you don't need to fetch it
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ReactComponent) // decorate React component with Redux state
```

And finally, access single object from Redux state in your React component:

```
import React from 'react';

const ReactComponent = ({ heroes }) => {

  console.log(heroes) // will log the redux state tree

  const markZuckerburg = heroes.data[0] // will log {name: "Mark Zuckerburg", description: "Facebook CEO"}
  const sherylSandberg = heroes.data[1] // will log {name: "Sheryl Sandberg", description: "Facebook COO"}

  return (
    <div> {markZuckerburg.name} </div>
    <div> {sherylSandberg.name} </div>
  )
}

export default React Component
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch data from Redux using hooks, with the `useSelector` hook.

Example of a redux state consisting a "todos" array, fetching a single one:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

export const TodoListItem = props => {
  const todo = useSelector(state => state.todos[props.id])
  return <div>{todo.text}</div>
}
```